# Why is this an invalid eta conversion?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I am working on a pretty basic problem in haskell. I was trying to count the number of lower case letters in a String. My solution is this

```
import Data.Char

lowercaseCount :: String -> Int
lowercaseCount x = length $ filter isLower x
```

I was looking at the actual implementation of `lowercaseCount` and saw that it seemed like it should have been able to under-go an eta reduction. I tried this

```
lowercaseCount = length $ filter isLower
```

but GHC yelled at me saying

> Couldn't match expected type `[Char] -> Int`
>                     with actual type `Int`

I was wondering why this eta reduction is illegal, and if there was a way to make this function able to be in an eta-reduced form.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yep. That was it. I'm embarrassed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use function composition instead of application. Because you're only partially applying `filter`, it results in a function.

You need to compose it into `length` instead of applying it:

```
lowercaseCount = length . filter isLower
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Accept is coming in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 9):

```
lowercaseCount x = length $ filter isLower x
```

means

```
lowercaseCount x = length (filter isLower x)    -- (1)
```

while

```
lowercaseCount = length $ filter isLower
```

means

```
lowercaseCount = length (filter isLower)
```

which after eta-expansion becomes

```
lowercaseCount x = length (filter isLower) x  -- (2)
```

It should now be evident that (1) and (2) are not equivalent. The latter passes two arguments to `length`, triggering a type error.

Comment: This is a great way of breaking it down.